# error when using while loop in bash script

Tags: linux, unix, shell-script

I am getting an error `2: [: missing ]` when using the following `while` loop:

```
#!/bin/sh
while ["$INPUT_STRING" != "bye"]
do
  echo "please type something (bye quits) "
  read INPUT_STRING
  echo "you tuped : $INPUT_STRING "
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add spaces around `while`'s condition:

```
while [ "$INPUT_STRING" != "bye" ]
```

This may seem a bit strange for people with a programming background but the reasons are these:

1. `while` expects a command list.  Control flow depends on the exit status of this command: as long as it is zero, the body continues to be executed.
2. `[ expression ]` is an alternative form of `test expression`.  Here, `test` is a command that evaluates the expression and returns its value in the form of the command's exit status.  It makes sure to return an exit status of zero if the expression (logically) evaluates to a `true` Boolean value, so that it can be used in `if` and `while` commands.
3. In fact, both `test` and `[` are executable files in linux (typically they are found at `/usr/bin`).  Some shells however, like `bash`, use internal commands with the same names.
4. As `test` and `[` are (technically) simple commands, their arguments should be separated from the command's name and among each other with one or more white characters.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: These were intended not to be complete statements, but just the part containing `while` and the condition.  I removed them, as they did not add something important to the answer.  Of course you are right about what happens when omitting the spaces around the `!=` operator.